# SQL - How to add a column which shows the average of another column where record-specific criteria are met

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| PersonID | Class | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 110 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | 60 |

I need the new column to show the average of Score for each PersonID across all Scores for which class is less than or equal to that in the current record.

Here's what it should look like:

| PersonID | Class | Score | Avg_Score_ClassLessThanOrEqual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90 | 90 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 95 |
| 1 | 3 | 110 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 | 40 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 | 45 |
| 2 | 3 | 60 | 50 |

Is this possible?  I've tried partition by and sum(Case when), but I'm just starting out learning.  I believe I need something like the pseudocode `Partition by PersonID where PersonID = PersonID and Class <= Class`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT t1.personid, t1.class, t1.score, 
    avg(t2.score) as average_score
FROM yourtable AS t1
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t2
        ON t1.personid = t2.personid
        AND t2.class <= t1.class
GROUP BY t1.personid, t1.class, t1.score
```

**EDIT**:

I added the following part to match your request in the comments:

```sql
SELECT t1.personid, t1.class, t1.score, 
    avg(CASE WHEN t2.class <= t1.class THEN t2.score END) AS average_lower, 
    avg(CASE WHEN t2.class > t1.class THEN t2.score END) AS average_higher
FROM yourtable AS t1
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t2
        ON t1.personid = t2.personid
GROUP BY t1.personid, t1.class, t1.score
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this one a shot.  I'm running the code that the first commenter provided and it's still going at 45 minutes, so maybe this will be faster.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I was missing a `group by` in the solution, sorry. Just added it.

Comment: That worked and appears to be much faster!  I think I'm almost there.  I actually need two fields: (avg of score if class <= class) and (avg of score if class > class), because I'm creating a metric that is a function of both of those.  It looks to me like with the structure of your code I'd need to basically run it twice and join the tables, yeah?

Comment: Glad it helped! I have edited my response to add the 'greater than' field. If it was helpful please consider marking my response as correct by clicking on the checkmark ✔️

Comment: Didn't know about the checkmark... clicked, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(t2.score)
        from t t2
        where t2.personid = t.personid and t2.class <= t.class
       ) as avg_score_less_than
from t;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(personid, class, score)`.  Note:  This uses `class` for the "less than or equal to part".

Hmmm . . . Actually, you can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(score) over (partition by personid order by class) as avg_score_less_than
from t;
```

Comment: Dataset has about 750k records, it's still running using the first form you sent.  I'll give the second a shot, it looks like it will run a lot faster.

Comment: Actually - in your second solution, this would average all the scores for a given PersonID, not just those that are less than or equal, right?

Comment: @No_Idea1299 . . . No, the `order by` has an implicit `range between unbounded preceding and current row` so it takes the average of earlier classes (as expressed there) or lower scores -- if you use `order by score`.